# How do you invoke functions from other PHP files WITHOUT including the HTML of a PHP file?

Tags: php, html, function

At the moment, I am trying to use the `include` keyword to get functions from other files. However, recently, I have been trying to access only functions, but as a side effect I get the HTML code too from the PHP file. How do I **only** get the PHP functions?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you can't. You should consider moving the functions into its own file(s) instead of declaring them within a file that contains HTML.